# Como achar coordenadas de ponto específico

Tags: javascript, google-maps, coordenadas

preciso das coordenadas de um ponto específico do Google Maps. Tipo como se eu clicasse num ponto e de alguma forma a API me mostrasse a cordenada do mnsm. Pois vou precisa calcular distancia entre 2 pontos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui são mostrados exemplos em página HTML e aplicação Android.

1. **Página HTML**

   O exemplo a seguir abre um popup quando você clica no mapa:

   ```js
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
       <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           window.onload = function () {
               var mapOptions = {
                   center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.9300, 72.8200),
                   zoom: 14,
                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
               };
               var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
               var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
               var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
               google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
                   alert("Latitude: " + e.latLng.lat() + "\r\nLongitude: " + e.latLng.lng());
               });
           }
       </script>
       <div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
       </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

   Veja o [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teepuw2j/) funcionando.
2. **Android**

   Veja o exemplo a serguir para android:

   Classe **EventDemoActivity**:

   ```java
   public class EventsDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity
      implements OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener {

         private GoogleMap mMap;
         private TextView mTapTextView;

         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.events_demo);

             mTapTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tap_text);

             setUpMapIfNeeded();
         }

         private void setUpMap() //If the setUpMapIfNeeded(); is needed then...
         {
             mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
             mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
         }

         @Override
         public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
             mTapTextView.setText("tapped, point=" + point);
         }

         @Override
         public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
             mTapTextView.setText("long pressed, point=" + point);
         }
   }
   ```

   Layout **events_demo.xml**:

   ```xml
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">
     <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tap_text"
       android:text="@string/tap_instructions"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
     <fragment
       android:id="@+id/map"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

   Você pode baixar o exemplo completo [aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code).

Comment: OOOps. Esqueci de dizer q é para android kkkkkkkk

Comment: Vou adicionar um exemplo para Android

Comment: Mas cara, consegui achar o ponto do local que eu queria!! Agora ja consegui calcular a distancia entre este ponto e outro que irá variar de acordo com a localização do usuário. Use a classe Location.

Comment: aah sim, vou usar, vlw cara!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Código referente a cálculo de distancia entre 2 pontos:

```java
public double distanciaEmMetros(double lat1, double long1, double lat2, double long2) {
    final Location start = new Location("Start Point");
    start.setLatitude(lat1);
    start.setLongitude(long1); //

    final Location finish = new Location("Finish Point");
    finish.setLatitude(lat2);
    finish.setLongitude(long2);

    final float distance = start.distanceTo(finish);

    return distance;
}
```